# What is the Android 'abort' error and why Firebase Crashlytics does not catch it?

Tags: android, firebase, crash, obfuscation, crashlytics

My Android app is suffering from an'abort' error after recent update.
But I don't know why this problem happens and how can I debug it.
This 'abort' error occurred especially on Android 10 and 11.
It is not recorded on Firebase Crashlytics, I can see it only on Google play console.
The log is as below.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004ef24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 000000000053b078  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2340)
  #00  pc 000000000001394c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 00000000000130cc  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+312)
  #00  pc 000000000058e1d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingException() const+1836)
  #00  pc 00000000001c15cc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::FindClass(art::Thread*, char const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000380c34  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::FindClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+1144)
  #00  pc 00000000000200d4  /data/app/~~0HXm4UzxwERXczUAACEC9g==/com.****.****-L0QwKgab-Tg3REmBFsu7iA==/lib/arm64/libmm.so
  #00  pc 0000000000020b90  /data/app/~~0HXm4UzxwERXczUAACEC9g==/com.****.****-L0QwKgab-Tg3REmBFsu7iA==/lib/arm64/libmm.so
  #00  pc 00000000000b6234  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050e64  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

I applied 'View Binding' to this update.
Could it be an cause?
Also I wonder if an Android app can be alive when 'abort' error occurred.

Please help me...

- libmm is a file of an obfuscation solution which we applied to the app. It is a binary obfuscation solution and it is run before application runs on memory as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know anything about Crashlytics, so I don't know why you don't see those crashes there. But the stacktrace does give some clues about where you should start looking for the source of the crash: it appears that your app includes some native library named `libmm`, which at some point tries to call `FindClass` while there's a pending Java exception. You're not allowed to do that, so that triggers an abort.

Comment: @Michael Yes, libmm is a file of an obfuscation solution which we applied to the app. It is a binary obfuscation solution and it is run before application runs on memory as far as I know.
Then, can I assume that the crash occurs when the application starts?